# Convert day, hour and minute to UTC - node.js

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I will get time input from the user for scheduling a task. The options are as follows,

- Day of the week, hour and minute **(or)**
- Day of the month, hour and minute **(or)**
- Month of the year, hour and minute **(or)**

User can be in any timezone. I have modeled my database table to store the user input as a configuration.
In my table I will calculate the next_run_at and populate it, so that poller can find the jobs to run based on it and execute.

To be timezone agnostic, my next_run_at should be in UTC. 
Is there a way to convert the above mentioned configuration(Day, hour, minute) alone in UTC and store it?

**TL;DR** I know we can convert a date to specific timezone. Is there a way to convert the combination of just day, hour and minute alone to UTC?

Comment: I think [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) can be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a date from the day, hours, and minutes you have. Convert it to UTC and get the day, hours, and months values back.

But I think there will be edge cases as to which month the day corresponds to.

`23:00 28th Feb PST` will be `06:00 1st Mar UTC`;

`23:00 28th Mar PST` will be `06:00 29th Mar UTC`

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there a way to convert the combination of just day, hour and minute alone to UTC?

No, there is not a general way to do that.  You must have the full date and time, including year, month, day, hour and minute.  Otherwise you cannot be certain if daylight saving time is in effect, or if the standard time has changed.

You will have to assume some of the data you don't have.  For example, you could make an assumption that the data is relative to "now".  Just understand you will get different results depending on when you run the code.

Of course, this doesn't apply if there's only a single fixed offset for the time zone in question, such as Arizona being fixed to UTC-7.  Just you can't assume this in the general case of any time zone of the world.